# Как отладить сериализацию под Mono?

Tags: xml, mono, c#, monodevelop, сериализация

Мы пропробовали развернуть наш продукт на Linux-кластере и столкнулись с ошибкой сериализации. Под отладчиком в `MonoDevelop` эта ошибка не воспроизводится, только через командную строку mono. С помощью отладочной печати выяснилось, что внутри сериализатора (`XmlSerializer`) возникает `InvalidCastException`, но что дальше делать - непонятно.

Можно ли хотя бы запустить отладчик под mono при наличии установленного .NET Framework?

Comment: Хм. А что вообще известно? Знаете, объект какого класса не смог сериализоваться? Исходники XmlSerializer'а есть? (Если нет, можно посмотреть Reflector'ом или ILSpy'ем на Windows, бинарная совместимость по идее должна быть.)

Comment: Он падает в том месте, где свойство помечено атрибутом `XmlAnyElement`. Там произвольный xml должен быть. А вообще, сегодня удалось сделать так, чтобы конкретно это место заработало. Так что вопрос скорее о том, как в целом с этим работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA)